# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): [AxiosError: Network Error] - React Native and Django

Tags: javascript, django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get the data from Django backend for my React Native project but im getting this error

`Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): [AxiosError: Network Error]`

im new to react native and django but ive done this before in react js but i dont know why i cant get it to work here

Here's My React Native Code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text } from "react-native";

// Components
import ProductCard from "../components/ProductCard";

export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProducts() {
      const { data } = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/");
      setProducts(data);
    }

    fetchProducts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
        {products.map((product) => (
          <View style={styles.productsContainer}>
            <ProductCard product={product} navigation={navigation} />
          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

I also added these to settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

Comment: Does your server run at the same machine as the application?

Comment: it is running at the same time

Comment: Try using your ip address instead of 127.0.0.1